# What exception should be thrown when there is no object associated with a key?

Tags: java, exception

I have an API where I am checking whether there are any existing objects available for a given key. If available, then update the existing object, otherwise create new object and save it.

If there is a case in which the key is available, but no object is linked to it, which exception should be thrown?

Comment: Could be looking for [NoSuchElementException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html)

Comment: @amit: That seems to be specific for `Enumeration`.

Comment: If your specification says that the given key actually has to exist, you could throw an `IllegalArgumentException` in case it doesn't.

Comment: A nullpointer comes close I suppose, but you could make your own custom error, since your API is custom as well

Comment: What exactly does 'the key is available, but no object is linked to it' mean?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon A link to a non-normative site is 'much better' how exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how you want to build your API. I think hhe first thing you need to decide is: should this exception be caught by caller or not necessarily? In other words, is it a **RuntimeException** or not?

I guess that if you want to throw an exception, it's because your data model should not have empty / null objects for a given key. So, I would argue for an **IllegalStateException** or **NoSuchElementException** , which extends **RuntimeException**. It means that the caller is not forced to catch the exception.

If you want to force caller to catch the exception I would suggest you create your own exception that just extends **Exception**

---

EDIT:

For instance, a class named "MissingValueException" and defined as follow:

```
public class MissingValueException extends Exception {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MissingValueException(final String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public MissingValueException(final String message, final Exception root) {
        super(message, root);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I want to stop operation if key is passed from UI but there is no object exist against key. For now I used [ObjectNotFoundException](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/ObjectNotFoundException.html) Is this right?

Comment: I just edited my proposition with an example. ObjectNotFoundException is used for EJB and comes in javax.ejb . While it can probably do the job without any issue, I think it's a better choice to write your own exception class without reusing other context-specific exceptions.

Comment: Thank you @Joel, ObjectNotFoundException works for me but writing customized exception is better option.